# floating pass of fully lazy lambda lifting?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, program-transformation

I'm reading [implementing functional languages: a tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/pj-lester-book/), and encountered a problem when implementing floating pass of fully lazy lambda lifting.

I would like to describe how floating works to make this question clear, if you are familiar with it, **just skip to the question below**.

The concept is introduced at page 246 in the paper, and mainly implemented at page 256-257.

In case of `let(rec)` expression, it says:

> we must put floated definitions of right-hand side before the `let(rec)` expression itself, since the right-hand side may depend on them.

for example:

```
\a ->
  let f = \b -> b + (let $mfe = a * a in $mfe)
  in f
```

The variable `$mfe` is a *maximal free expression (MFE)* which identified by previous pass, when dealing with `let f` expression, we float `f` out as one group and append it to `[(1, [($mfe, a * a)])]`, which was obtained from right-hand side of `let f`. Here, the first component `1` indicates the *free level* of the group.

When backtracking to `\a -> f` abstraction, we found that both `$mfe` and `f` are bound by it, hence we should install them here:

```
\a ->
  let $mfe = a * a
  in
    let f = \b -> b + $mfe
    in f
```

## The Question

Suppose we have a program like this:

```
f = \x -> \y ->
  letrec
    a = \p -> cons p (b x)
    b = \q -> cons q (a y)
  in pair (a 1) (b 2)
```

The *free level* of `b x` and `a y` will be 2, since `y` has level 2 and they are in a same group.

While *free level* of `cons p (b x)` and `cons q (a y)` is 3, thus `b x` and `a y` will be marked as MFEs (Did I make mistakes here?).

Using the algorithm given by SPJ, the program will be transformed into:

```
f = \x -> \y ->
  let $ay = a y -- `a` is not defined yet!
  in
    let $bx = b x -- and `b`
    in
      letrec
        a = \p -> cons p $bx
        b = \q -> cons q $ay
      in pair (a 1) (b 2)
```

I think the MFEs in the right-hand side of `let(rec)` expression should **not** escape the `let(rec)` scope whenever it referenced to the left-hand side, and the correct result might like this:

```
f = \x -> \y ->
  letrec
    $ay = a y
    $bx = b x
    a = \p -> cons p $bx
    b = \q -> cons q $ay
  in pair (a 1) (b 2)
```

Does the paper wrong? or I just misunderstood it.

Comment: without reading the book, you can't float `a y` above `letrec` which defines `a`, obviously, and your 2nd transformation looks correct.

Comment: @WillNess yes, just capture the floated definitions which has same free level with the let(rec) expression and put them together will fix this issue. But I'm not sure if I missed sth when reading the paper or made some mistakes.